# ResultSet getDate duplicating a date and failing so on

Tags: java, mysql, date, resultset

**Any idea of the reason of this behavior?**

From a test MySQL table with two columns

[image]

Using this data (dates from 1 to 31)

[image]

Retrieving the dates thru Java

```
public static void executeQuery (Connection conn){
        try {
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;
            String query = "SELECT recordId, testedDate FROM test_date;";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query) ;
            if(rs != null) {
                while(rs.next())
                    System.out.println(rs.getInt("recordId") + " - [" + rs.getDate("testedDate") + "]");
            }else {
                System.out.println("No results found!");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I am getting a duplicate date at record 15 and wrong dates from there to end.

[image]

Comment: Check timezone offset

Comment: Never use `java.sql.Date` and `rs.getDate()`. And even less for a column of data type `datetime`. `java.sql.Date` was a hack on top of the already poorly designed `java.util.Date` class and is fortunately long outdated. For this MySQL data type use `LocalDateTime` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API, and `rs.getObject("testedDate", LocalDateTime.class)`.

Comment: Is your time zone in North America or somewhere else where summer time (DST) began on March 14?

Comment: @OleV.V. LocalDateTime makes the trick, I am using CST and time changes until april 4th... although I am wondering why it offsets a whole day instead of just the time switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right solution depends on whether you really need to store only dates, or you need to store points in time.

1. For dates without time of day use `date` in MySQL and `LocalDate` in Java.
2. For points in time prefer `timestamp` in MySQL and `OffsetDateTime` in Java. MySQL stores `timestamp` values in UTC, so they define a point in time.
3. If you cannot change the data type in MySQL, with `datetime` the correct type to use in Java is `LocalDateTime`.

`LocalDate`, `OffsetDateTime` and `LocalDateTime` are all part of java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

To retrieve a type from java.time from your result set use its `getOnbject` method, not `getDate`. For example to get a `LocalDate`:

```
       rs.getObject("testedDate", LocalDate.class)
```

The other types are the same except you pass `OffsetDateTime.class` or `LocalDateTime.class` as the second argument.

Under no circumstances use `java.sql.Date` and `rs.getDate()`. The `java.sql.Date` class is a hack on top of the already poorly designed `java.util.Date` class. Fortunately both `Date` classes are long outdated (no pun intended).

### Why a whole day wrong?

> I am using CST …

While I cannot give you the whole story, the change happens on March 14, the same day where summer time (DST) begins in most of North America, including America/Chicago and America/Winnipeg time zones.

> although I am wondering why it offsets a whole day instead of just the time switch.

When printing a `java.sql.Date` only the date is printed, not the time of day. I bet that behind the scenes the time of day is 23:00 in those dates that appear to be one day too early. And 00:00 in the others, so internally the difference is only 1 hour.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Comment: Definitely I am considering to improve this legacy app since this is used everywhere, much appreciated the high quality of your response.